# C# Multithreading: Do I have to use locks when only getting objects from a list/dictionary?

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, thread-safety

I am currently working on a multithreaded c# application.

In my case, I have a list/dictionary, which is assigned and filled in the main-thread while the application is starting up. The list will never be modified again. I only use the list to get objects.

Do I have to use locks?

```
lock(list) { var test = list[0]; }
```

or can I access the object directly?

I know, if I access the object in the list, the object has to be thread-safe.

Comment: No, you don't need locks for read-only operations. Why do you need to write a multi-threaded application? Is there something you can't do with TPL or Rx?

Comment: I didn't know there is such thing as TPL. But this libary looks awesome! But i don't think this will serve my purpose. For my application, i need about ~1000 workers/objects/threads to respond to different websockets multiple times a second.

Comment: Woah! 1,000 threads? You do know that the overhead for creating a thread is **at least 1 MB**. You're using up over 1 GB just in creating your threads. This is exactly why you should be using TPL or Rx (or similar). They manage the threads for you. I think you need to give us more detail on what you're doing so that we can suggest a better way. This discussion about dictionary locking is going to be the least of your concerns.

Comment: I think you should ask a new question about your approach.

Comment: When a user logs into the "client" the server (my application) will create a new object with a websocket connection using its own thread. Every use has his own thread. I like this way of doing it, because its very object orientated. TPL looks very procedual.I use [websocket-sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading is not a problem. But be sure that unexpected behaviors can appear if someone else is writing/deleting.  When you are reading

if this list is prepared before and not changed after this you could access the object without locking which is also faster.

But be really aware that you should strongly avoid and modification action to happend when you read from the collection.

When you need also the writing operations then you would need synchronization like with ReaderWriterLockSlim or have a look at the  [system.collections.concurrent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't change the content of the list/array, there is no *immediate* need for locks.

**But** I would suggest to implement some synchronization (like locks) anyway. Can you be sure that you won't change your application in the next years so that you will change the content later at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, reading is not a problem. But as you said, you are populating this collection at start up. But you have not mentioned at what point are you starting to read. So presumably there can be unexpected behaviours. You have to use thread safe collections for that. For an example you can use a blocking collection for this purpose.

Here is the MSDN article which explains more about thread safe collections [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Please don't link to external site. Put the content in the answer and link only as a supporting reference.

Comment: External link removed. Was that the reason for down vote?

Comment: Well, the link sealed the deal, but the advice that the OP has to use a thread-safe collection is not really correct in this situation.

Comment: And your edit didn't bring the content in to the answer. You've just made the link look pretty.

Comment: Ok. I added more content. I also just noted the persons who suggested the same thing getting +1s.

Answer (score 0):

Lock is used to avoid fetching dirty reads if there's other thread . Since you won't change it, `list` is lock-free.

If you really want to prevent some unexpected changes for debugging (get error when it happens), you can declare it as const.